# AWS Glue Job: SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException when trying to write parquet file to S3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a table in the AWS Glue catalog that has datatypes of all strings and the files are stored as parquet files in S3. I want to create a Glue job that will simply read the data in from that catalog, partition the files by the date, then write those files back out to S3. However, I keep getting a SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException saying that the parquet column cannot be converted.

I have tried the ApplyMapping function to make sure all of the data is represented as strings in the DynamicFrame

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "processed", table_name = "compass_2_daily_tkt_parquet")

mapping_dyf = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = tkt, mappings = [("tkt_id", "string", "tkt_id", "string"), ("tkt_nbr", "string", "tkt_nbr", "string"), ("tran_nbr", "string", "tran_nbr", "string"), ("pnr_ref", "string", "pnr_ref", "string"), ("provider_id", "string", "provider_id", "string"), ("carr_nbr", "string", "carr_nbr", "string"), ("agency_nbr", "string", "agency_nbr", "string"), ("point_of_orig_arpt_cd", "string", "point_of_orig_arpt_cd", "string"), ("dt_of_issue", "string", "dt_of_issue", "string"), ("curr_type_cd", "string", "curr_type_cd", "string"), ("fare_amt", "string", "fare_amt", "string"), ("fare_curr_type_cd", "string", "fare_curr_type_cd", "string"), ("tax_amt", "string", "tax_amt", "string"), ("fee_amt", "string", "fee_amt", "string"), ("comm_amt", "string", "comm_amt", "string"), ("doc_amt", "string", "doc_amt", "string"), ("pfc_amt", "string", "pfc_amt", "string"), ("proc_ped", "string", "proc_ped", "string"), ("intl_sale_ind", "string", "intl_sale_ind", "string"), ("e_tkt_ind", "string", "e_tkt_ind", "string"), ("fare_calc_ind", "string", "fare_calc_ind", "string"), ("tour_cd", "string", "tour_cd", "string"), ("dist_channel", "string", "dist_channel", "string"), ("cntry_cd", "string", "cntry_cd", "string"), ("stat_cd", "string", "stat_cd", "string"), ("tran_cd", "string", "tran_cd", "string"), ("data_source_cd", "string", "data_source_cd", "string"), ("data_sharing_id", "string", "data_sharing_id", "string"), ("load_ts", "timestamp", "load_ts", "timestamp"), ("net_fare_amt", "string", "net_fare_amt", "string"), ("suppl_fare_amt", "string", "suppl_fare_amt", "string"), ("contributed_ind", "string", "contributed_ind", "string"), ("print_cpui", "string", "print_cpui", "string"), ("file_id", "string", "file_id", "string"), ("print_fare_basis", "string", "print_fare_basis", "string"), ("waiver_cd", "string", "waiver_cd", "string"), ("comp_conj_cd", "string", "comp_conj_cd", "string"), ("tot_amt", "string", "tot_amt", "string"), ("bulk_ticketing_cd", "string", "bulk_ticketing_cd", "string"), ("equivalent_fare_amt", "string", "equivalent_fare_amt", "string"), ("equivalent_fare_curr_type_cd", "string", "equivalent_fare_curr_type_cd", "string"), ("fare_amt_usd", "string", "fare_amt_usd", "string"), ("tax_amt_usd", "string", "tax_amt_usd", "string"), ("doc_amt_usd", "string", "doc_amt_usd", "string"), ("fare_amt_eur", "string", "fare_amt_eur", "string"), ("tax_amt_eur", "string", "tax_amt_eur", "string"), ("doc_amt_eur", "string", "doc_amt_eur", "string"), ("depart_dt", "string", "depart_dt", "string"), ("trip_type_cd", "string", "trip_type_cd", "string"), ("tkt_dest_cd", "string", "tkt_dest_cd", "string"), ("dds_tkt_rndmzn_pcg", "string", "dds_tkt_rndmzn_pcg", "string")])

tkt_df = mapping_dyf.toDF().withColumn("filename", input_file_name())

tkt_df.repartition("filename").write.partitionBy("filename").mode("append").parquet("s3://landing-spot")

tkt_df.write.parquet("s3://landing-spot", partitionBy=["filename"])

datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = tkt_dyf, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://landing-spot/", "partitionKeys": ["filename"]}, format = "parquet")

job.commit()
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.constructConvertNotSupportedException(VectorizedColumnReader.java:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBinaryBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:220)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
... 28 more
2019-08-07 19:57:41,651 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 7] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logError(91)) - Exception in task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file s3://file.parquet. Column: [tran_nbr], Expected: double, Found: BINARY
```

This confuses me since I am applying the mapping to the DynamicFrame, but when the process goes to write the data out to S3, it seems as if AWS Glue tries to infer the schema all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding
`conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", False)`.

More info about Vectorised Parquet Reading in [this](https://dataninjago.com/2021/12/12/databricks-deep-dive-4-vectorised-parquet-reading/) incredible article.